# Declaring <!doctype html> adding a 2px padding-top to font element

Tags: html, padding, doctype

Here's some simple HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{ padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:normal; }
            .pingBtCon{ display:block; margin:0px; border:1px solid; }
            .pingFavoriteMe{ font-size:10px; color:#666; cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; }
            .pingFavoriteMe:hover{ color:#333; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="pingBtCon"><a class="pingFavoriteMe">Favorite</a></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run it in Chrome, it adds a `2px` `padding-top` to the `div.pingBtCon`. Thus its total height becomes `17px` which should otherwise be only `15px`. And it doesn't look so good.

But surprisingly, when I remove `<!doctype html>`, `.pingBtCon` becomes ok with no `padding-top`.

What's happening?

[image: With <!doctype html>] 
[image: without <!doctype html>]

Comment: Don't use `font`. It's deprecated.

Comment: using div, does the same

Comment: Actually, [`font` is *obsolete* as of HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/font). Wizz-bang!

Comment: What browser? Could it be triggering/disabling quirks mode, thus messing up the expected behavior?

Comment: If you use no `doctype`, you're asking the browser to interpret it. You can, of course, use normalize.css or whatnot. But use a `doctype` and express your elements styles as you see fit.

Comment: Yes, quirks mode vs. standards mode. There will be rendering differences.

Comment: http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Comment: If it's a link, use `<a>`, if it's a button, use `button`. Use a `div` if it's neither of those.

Comment: @AramKocharyan using a div, shows same result

Comment: Yes, but showing the same result isn't the point of having different tags. Functionally speaking, a div isn't a link.

Comment: @AramKocharyan, i mean to say that, using a div also adds a padding-top

Answer (score 1):

When you add the doctype, you put the browser into standards mode. One important difference between standards mode and the other modes (quirks and almost standards), is that the font height of the containing block-level box is taken into account when calculating the height of the line boxes it contains.

So, without the standards mode doctype the div with class pingBtCon, contains one line-box, whose height is proportional to the height of the "Favorite" text, i.e. k * (10px).

With the standarda mode doctyoe,  the div with class pingBtCon, contains one line-box, whose height is proportional to the maximum of the height of the "Favorite" text and the height of the font as specified for the div (which in your case inherits its font-size from the body element). i.e. k * max(10px, 12px).

So with the standards mode doctype, the line box is slightly higher, and therefore, so is its containing div.

To fix it, simply set the font-size of the div with class pingBtCon to be the same as that of the a element with class pingFavoriteMe, i.e. 10px.

So add `.pingBtCon { font-size:10px; }`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [deprecated](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_deprecated_tags.htm) `font` tag. There's no reason to do so when you can use CSS.

```html
<a class="pingFavoriteMe pingBtCon">Favorite</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

[All new web pages are required to have a doctype](http://developers.whatwg.org/syntax.html#the-doctype) to put you into standards mode. Not using a doctype puts you into [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and it's like 1999 all over again where margins and padding among other things are all inside out, to put it simply.

Leave the doctype in and make sure it's the first thing you put on every page before you add anything else lest you leave yourself in for a world of hurt as you continue to have issues like you are now.

Comment: Thanks for the speech but you didn't answer the question.

Comment: @JackMarchetti I answered the question just fine and, if you would notice, it's similar to one of the others. The guy is adding/removing the doctype and questioning why stuff moves on him. If you need further education, ask your own question.